# Are there any security vulnerabilities to allowing unfiltered user input inside curl_setopt PHP function?

Tags: php, security, curl

If you were to allow an unfiltered query string based on whatever the user types so that cURL does a GET from a certain URL, are there any vulnerabilities in letting them put whatever they want inside the cURL function curl_setopt? This is assuming that the source URL itself is an API service that is properly validated, so I am only inquiring about vulnerabilities that would affect the system running cURL. Thank you.

Comment: PHP takes care of strings that submitted by user, there is no code injection vulnerability for cURL, however, if that input used for building query, you can validate it before sending to the API

Comment: The api should be doing it's own filtering and sanitizing of user inputs.

Comment: Thank you guys, yes the API itself would validate any incoming data. I was only concerned with whether the actual string could do something malicious from within cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two vulnerabilities in older versions of libcurl (that's used by the PHP/CURL extension) that can lead to undesired effects if you let users pass in whatever URL they want:

1 - [curl URL sanitization vulnerability](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20120124.html)

2 - [libcurl Arbitrary File Access](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20090303.html)

Comment: Hi, looks like the first list item applies to my cURL version. However, if all my CURLOPT_URL's are prefixed with http:// and I'm not using imap, pop3, or smtp for anything, then that vulnerability would not apply, right? Or can this prefix be bypassed in any way and turned into imap, pop3, or smtp?

Comment: if you always prefix it with http:// then it won't apply unless you allow libcurl to follow redirects to such protocols